# Sites cookies lost on page redirect

Tags: force.com-sites, cookies

We have an intranet Sites application (no Site Login used). Recently, I was extending the application to use cookies across page redirects rather than URL parameters for shared information.

To start, I created a secure Cookie in a page action method:

```
PageReference somePage1Action() {
   ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new List<Cookie> {
        new Cookie('secureCookie','{"cookieSet" : true}',null,7200,true)
   }; 
   PageReference resPg = Page.somePage2;
   resPg.setRedirect(true);
   return resPg;
}
```

when Page2 was displayed as a redirect, there was no Cookie named `secureCookie`. The controller code:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('secureCookie');
```

returned null (!?!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small test program that yielded the answer:

```
public with sharing class CookieController {

    private static PageReference COOKIEPAGE1 = Page.CookiePage1;
    private static PageReference COOKIEPAGE2 = Page.CookiePage2;

    public String getSecureCookieValue() {
      return ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('secureCookie') != null 
        ? ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('secureCookie').getValue() 
        : 'no secure cookie found';}
    public String getInsecureCookieValue() {
      return ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('insecureCookie') != null 
        ? ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('inSecureCookie').getValue() 
        : 'no insecure cookie found';}

    //  ---constructor---
    public CookieController() {
        if (apexPages.currentPage().getURL().contains('CookiePage1')) { // delete any extant cookies
            ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new List<Cookie> {   new Cookie('secureCookie','{"cookieSet" : true}',null,0,true),
                                                                    new Cookie('insecureCookie','{"cookieSet" : true}',null,0,false)});
        }
    }

    public PageReference cookiePage1Action() {
        ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new List<Cookie> {   new Cookie('secureCookie','{"cookieSet" : true}',null,7200,true),
                                                                new Cookie('insecureCookie','{"cookieSet" : true}',null,7200,false)}
                                          );
        COOKIEPAGE2.setRedirect(true);
        return COOKIEPAGE2;
    }

    public PageReference cookiePage2Action() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VF landing page**

```
<apex:page controller="CookieController" cache="false" action="{!cookiePage1Action}">
<h1>Cookie page 1</h1>
</apex:page>
```

**Landing page redirects to this page (that displays cookie value)**

```
<apex:page controller="CookieController" cache="false" action="{!cookiePage2Action}">
<h1>Cookie page 2</h1>
    <p>Secure Cookie Value: <apex:outputText value="{!securecookieValue}"/></p>   

    <p>Insecure Cookie Value: <apex:outputText value="{!insecurecookieValue}"/></p> 
</apex:page>
```

when this page displayed, I got this:

[image]

and by this time, the answer was staring me in the face. When the site had been setup back in 2009, the `Require Secure Connections` check box was unchecked:
[image]

Checking the box and repeating the test yielded expected results:

[image]