# How to obtain the cookies of one PageReference in another

Tags: apex, visualforce, cookies

I have a VF page '/apex/CarView' with a table of cars with columns - Name, Model, Color etc. The page has a button 'Print Cars'. The user can sort the cars based on the columns. I have to persist the sort order selected by user and use the same orders in Print Cars page which open in a new tab.

CarManager.cls

```
String sortOrders = 'Name, Color, Model'
Cookie cookieObj = new Cookie('SortColumns', sortOrders , null, -1, true);

PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
pageRef.getCookies().put('SortColumns', cookieObj);
```

Url : /apex/CarsView?clc=0&Id=a175w000006KM83AAG&isdtp=p1&ltn_app_id=06m5w0000024jMUAAY&nonce=4221021721a24e6f3e6c201f08d26dfb6ae1a13144d6b16eb422f0b849f5ee1c&sfdcIFrameHost=web&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fna172.lightning.force.com&tour=

But when I use this URL to obtain the PageReference and then the cookies, I get a null.

How do I pass cookies between pages? Or, How can i read one page's cookies in another?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE! I assume the UX is Lightning Experience rather than Classic? Please add this detail to the question with a simple [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/316381/edit).

Comment: I suspect this may be a simple issue of the use of ```getCookies().put``` instead of using ```setCookies```. I've not used the API myself, so if you have to query cookies to preserve them try ```Map<String, Cookie> cookies = pageRef.getCookies(); cookies.put('apex__SortColumns', cookieObj); pageRef.setCookies(cookies.values());```. Note that "apex__" prefix is automatically added by setCookies and only "apex__" prefixed cookies are returned by getCookies. To ensure any existing "Sort Columns" value is replaced explicitly use the prefix as shown.

Comment: if Sites application: see [this q&a](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117539/sites-cookies-lost-on-page-redirect)